# How to provide a stylesheet for rendering PDFs?

Tags: css, coldfusion, pdf-generation, coldfusion-10

Following on from a previous question, I have managed to get the 'screen' version (HTML) of a document into PDF format using the `<cfdocument format="pdf">` tag. I need the styling of the PDF to be different to that of the screen version for obvious reasons (e.g. different header styles).

I know that you can use Media Queries in CSS so that different styles are applied for printing, screen, tv etc. But how do I supply a different set of CSS styles to the `<cfdocument>` tag so that it renders correctly?

My initial solution was to apply a class to the containing `div` of the `<cfdocument>` tag called `.pdf` and then write new styles for the content based on that class inside my main CSS file. So for example a style would be `.pdf h1 {font-size:20px;}`. The CFML would look like this:

```
<cfdocument type="pdf">
<link href="/css/mainStyleSheet.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
 <div class="pdf">
  <h1>Document Title</h1>
  ... {document body here} ...
 </div>
</cfdocument>
```

Is there a better way to do this at all? Is there anyway to pass a different stylesheet just for PDF rendering? Can it be done with Media Queries perhaps?

Comment: _"Is there a better way to do this at all?"_ Yeah: **not using cfdocument**. You'll get a few steps forward with a correct doctype and importing stylesheets, but you'll soon be back asking why certain constructs aren't working or random spaces are appearing or some other quirk. _Use something else._

Comment: But its very convenient to use this feature of ColdFusion. I would really like to avoid using as few plugins and external dependencies as possible.

Comment: Convenient? Yes. Worth the effort? No. But since you seem determined to go down the difficult path, try adding the style sheet using a file system path like `c:\my\path\to\the\css\file.css` Also, probably better to use a separate CSS file for the PDF. Or use some external library, like http://wkhtmltopdf.org/

Comment: And it's very inconvenient and frustrating wasting _weeks_ of time trying to get something working, before discovering alternatives that _just work_. Listen to the advice of those of us that have done this before, because we're not going to waste time answering questions that only exist due to some nonsenical aversion to using working software.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How are you generating the PDF, via a parameter in the querystring? Something like `index.cfm?page=foo&format=pdf`? If you aren't, you could easily add a parameter like that, then in your CFM:

```
<link href="/css/mainStyleSheet.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<cfif structKeyExists(url, "format") AND url.format EQ "pdf">
     <link href="/css/pdfStyleSheet.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
</cfif>
```

`pdfStyleSheet.css` would contain only the CSS overrides for the PDF.

Comment: I was using a form variable, but this example worked fine for me. Thank you!